# How should I remove nodes in d3-force?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I want to remove node when click this node, so I just remove the node when click with `nodes = nodes.filter(v => v.id !== d.id)`.Actually, it works at the first time, but it doesn't work next.

Here is my code:

```js
uuid = function uuid() {
  var template = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  return template.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
    var r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
    if (c === 'y') r = (r & 3) | 8;
    return r.toString(16);
  });
}

const width = 800;
const height = 400;
const count = 10;
let nodes = Array.from({length: count}).map((_, i) => ({x: width / count * i + 20, y: height / 2, id: uuid()}));
const svg = d3.select("svg").attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
let node = svg
    .selectAll(".node");


const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .stop();

function update() {  
  node = node.data(nodes, d=> d.id)
    .join("g")
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 12)
    .attr("cursor", "move")
    .attr("fill", "#ccc")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";})
    .on("click", (ev, d) => {
      nodes = nodes.filter(v => v.id !== d.id);
      update();
  });
  
  simulation.nodes(nodes);

  if (simulation.alpha() <= 1) {
    simulation.alpha(1);
    simulation.restart();
  }
}

update()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to *append* a circle for the new nodes, for any other nodes, appending a circle means that the next time you click, there's actually two circles to remove, not one!

`.join()` can be passed three functions, that you can apply to the `enter`, `update`, and `exit` selections. These are executed, the return values are joined, and then you can do things to all selections combined.

In this case, I moved all the one-time `circle` logic to the `enter` part, being careful not to return the `circle`, but the `g` element that you first appended. If you return the `circle`, it will combine these with the existing `g elements and the logic will break.

```js
uuid = function uuid() {
  var template = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  return template.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
    var r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0;
    if (c === 'y') r = (r & 3) | 8;
    return r.toString(16);
  });
}

const width = 800;
const height = 400;
const count = 10;
let nodes = Array.from({length: count}).map((_, i) => ({x: width / count * i + 20, y: height / 2, id: uuid()}));
const svg = d3.select("svg").attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
let node = svg
    .selectAll(".node");

const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .stop();

function update() {  
  console.log(nodes.length);
  node = node.data(nodes, d=> d.id)
    .join(
      enter => {
        const g = enter
          .append("g")
          .attr("class", "node");
        g
          .append("circle")
          .attr("r", 12)
          .attr("cursor", "move")
          .attr("fill", "#ccc")
          .attr("stroke", "#000")
          .attr("stroke-width", "1.5px");
        return g;
      },
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
    .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";})
    .on("click", (ev, d) => {
      nodes = nodes.filter(v => v.id !== d.id);
      update();
  });
  
  simulation.nodes(nodes);

  if (simulation.alpha() <= 1) {
    simulation.alpha(1);
    simulation.restart();
  }
}

update()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Wow, great.Thans you very much. But I have a question, why the nodes move every time when I click? Can I avoid this?

Comment: That is because of the `forceSimulation` you apply. You drag everything to the center with it. If you remove that, the nodes stay in place

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what is the problem but take a look at the DOM your code produce.
There are a list of `g` elements, each `g` contains a lot of nested `circle`. It's very strange and it doesn't make sense.
So I suggest you to refactor your code to have something like:

```html
<svg>
  <circle class="node#1"... />
  <circle class="node#2"... />
  <circle class="node#3"... />
  <circle class="node#4"... />
</svg>
```

And then, when use clicks on a circle element, get the class name and remove that node

Comment: This can be helpful when you want to add labels to the nodes, for example. Keep in mind that experienced users have often reduced their problem to a [mre], leaving some of the decisions they made less clear. For people who are new to d3, or who have clearly followed an example, your statement generally holds, but beware of asking people to change a structure they might have chosen deliberately.